# `__dict__` of classes in Python

Tags: python, class

Code goes first,

```
#Python 2.7

>>>class A(object):
       pass

>>>a1 = A()
>>>a2 = A()

>>>A.__dict__
dict_proxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__module__': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None})
```

**Question**

1.what is `dict_proxy` and why use it?

2.`A.__dict__` contains an attr -- `'__dict': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>`. What is this? Is it for `a1` and `a2`? But objects of `A` have their own `__dict__`, don't they?

Answer (score 4):

For your fist question I quote from Fredrik Lundh: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t359039-dictproxy-what-is-this.html:

```
a CPython implementation detail, used to protect an internal data structure used
by new-style objects from unexpected modifications.
```

Answer (score 2):

For your second question:

```
>>> class A(object):
       pass

>>> a1 = A()
>>> a2 = A()
>>> a1.foo="spam"
>>> a1.__dict__
{'foo': 'spam'}
>>> A.bacon = 'delicious'
>>> a1.bacon
'delicious'
>>> a2.bacon
'delicious'
>>> a2.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#314>", line 1, in <module>
    a2.foo
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> a1.__dict__
{'foo': 'spam'}
>>> A.__dict__
dict_proxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, 'bacon': 'delicious', '__module__': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None})
```

Does this answer your question?

If not, dive deeper: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4877655/1324545

Comment: I just wanna know, why `A.__dict__` still contains a `'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>`, is this one for instances of `A`?

Comment: yes, but it is not a `__dict__`. it *implements* `__dict__` for the instances. this is explained in the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

dict_proxy prevents you from creating new attributes on a class object by assigning them to the `__dict__`. If you want to do that use `setattr(A, attribute_name, value)`.

a1 and a2 are instances of A and not class objects. They don't have the protection A has and you can assign using `a1.__dict__['abc'] = 'xyz'`