# How to create class object without __dict__

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

```
class B(type):
    __slots__ = ()

class A(metaclass=B):
    pass

A.test = "test"
```

`"A"` is instance of metaclass `"B"` and `"B"` have `__slots__` defined - why I have `__dict__` at class `A`? How I can create class object without `__dict__`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877290/what-is-the-dict-dict-attribute-of-a-python-class

Comment: Why do you want a class with no `__dict__`?  Maybe there is a way to solve the problem differently.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: Yes, I want a class with no \__dict__. Its strange that \__slots__ works in class<->instance and doesn't with metaclass<->class. I was thinking that built-in classes have no \__dict__, but apparently it's just not showing in dir(). E.g. hasattr(int, '\__dict__') == True

Comment: @Damamat: you haven't said *why* you want a class with no `__dict__`.  What's bad about having a dict? Can you explain?

Comment: Purely academic interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this; classes **always** have a `__dict__`.

You can only use `__slots__` on *classes* to produce instances without a `__dict__`, not on meta types. You'd normally only produce a few classes, so there is *not much point* in supporting `__slots__` on metaclasses.

Don't use `__slots__` to prevent attributes being set. Use `__setattr__` for that instead:

```
class NoAttributesClassMeta(type):
    def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
        if name not in cls.__dict__:
            raise AttributeError("Cannot set attributes")
        type.__setattr__(cls, name, value)
```

Comment: So there's no way to define a metaclass whose instances have `__slots__` defined (so _their_ instances won't have a `__dict__`)? This is what I think the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @martineau: I don't think so; why the test for `A.test = 'test'` then?

Comment: Oops, you're right about what the OP asked -- I was misunderstanding the question. +1

Answer (score 2):

`__slots__` won't stop you from setting an attribute to a class, you need to override `__setattr__` for that. Something like this should do it:

```
class B(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        dct['__slots__']  = ('x',)
        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)
    def __setattr__(cls, attr, val):
        if attr not in cls.__slots__:
            raise AttributeError('Can\'t set {!r}'.format(attr))
        else:
            type.__setattr__(cls, attr, val)

class A(metaclass=B):
    pass
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> A.x = 1
>>> A.y = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    A.y = 2
  File "C:\Python27\so.py", line 7, in __setattr__
    raise AttributeError('Can\'t set {!r}'.format(attr))
AttributeError: Can't set 'y'
```