# Python's "class is a dict" theory and consequences of adding class variables

Tags: python, class, dictionary

Just out of curiosity I'm playing with the `__dict__` attribute on Python classes.

I read somewhere that a "class" in python is kind of a dict, and calling `__dict__` on a class instance translate the instance into a dict... and I thought *"cool! I can use this!"*

But this lead me to doubts about the correctness and security of these actions.

For example, if I do:

```
class fooclass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg1 = arg

p = fooclass('value1')
print(p.__dict__)
p.__dict__['arg2'] = 'value2'
print(p.__dict__)
print(p.arg2)
```

I have this:

```
>>>{'arg1': 'value1'}
>>>{'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2'}
>>>value2
```

and that's fine, but:

1. Does the `fooclass` still have 1 attribute? How can I be sure?
2. Is it secure to add attributes that way?
3. Have you ever had cases where this came in handy?
4. I see that I can't do `fooclass.__dict__['arg2'] = 'value2'`.. so why this difference between a class and an instance?

Comment: Your introduction is mostly nonsense. "I read somewhere that a "class" in python is kind of a dict". No it isn't. Most classes _have_ a dict, called `__dict__` for each instance, and another one for the class itself, but that doesn't mean they _are_ a dict. "and calling __dict__ on a class instance translate the instance into a dict". No. __dict__ isn't a function; you can't call it on an instance. And I'm not sure what it would even mean to "translate it into a dict". Again, most classes' instances _have_ a dict, and you can _access_ it, but… that's not close to what you seem to be saying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are altering the attributes of the instance. Adding and removing from the `__dict__` is exactly what happens for *most* custom class instances.

The exception is when you have a class that uses [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots); instances of such a class do not have a `__dict__` attribute as attributes are stored in a different way.

Python is a language for consenting adults; there is no protection against adding attributes to instances with a `__dict__` in any case, so adding them to the dictionary or by using `setattr()` makes no difference.

Accessing the `__dict__` is helpful when you want to use existing `dict` methods to access or alter attributes; you can use `dict.update()` for example:

```
def Namespace(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

It is also helpful when trying to *read* an attribute on the instance for which there is a corresponding [*data descriptor*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) on the class; to bypass the latter you can access the `__dict__` on the instance to get to the attribute. You can also use this to test for attributes on the instance and ignore anything the class or the base classes might define.

As for `fooclass.__dict__`; you are confusing the *class* with the *instances* of a class. They are separate objects. A class is a different type of object, and `ClassObj.__dict__` is just a proxy object; you can still use `setattr()` on the class to add arbitrary attributes:

```
setattr(fooclass, 'arg2', 'value2')
```

or set attributes directly:

```
fooclass.arg2 = value2
```

A class needs to have a `__dict__` *proxy*, because the actual `__dict__` attribute is a descriptor object to provide that same attribute on instances. See [What is the __dict__.__dict__ attribute of a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877290/what-is-the-dict-dict-attribute-of-a-python-class)

Details about how Python objects work are documented in the [*Datamodel* reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: Great explanation; sadly, I'm out of votes for the day…