# Why can't an object's "__dict__" be stored in its __dict__?

Tags: python, python-descriptors

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4877655/12307991) it is mentioned that an instance's `"__dict__"` attribute can't be stored directly in its `__dict__`. Why?

Furthermore: If `instance.__dict__` gets transformed to `type(instance).__dict__["__dict__"].__get__(instance)`,
does this mean that `instance.x` gets transformed to `type(instance).__dict__["__dict__"].__get__(instance)["x"]` as well?

By the way: I have read the official descriptor documentation, but this still confuses me.

Thanks!