# Pass argument as member of a python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 python files 1 where only dictionary is saved
Example :

Dic.py

```
A={"1":{"a":1},    "2":{"b":2}}
```

And calldic.py

```
import dic

def todo(Value,Index):
    Data=dic.Value(Index)
    Print(Data)
```

As in the above code I am trying to pass argument as member of the dic.py file.

Can anyone please help me resolve this or correct me where I am wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Also, python is case-sensitive.

Comment: I don't want to write code for each key in the dictionary I want to have it as dynamic , in the above code if I call todo method as todo(A,1) Value = A and Index = 1 it should fetch the data in it.

Comment: Please do not rate it down as I am posting this from my mobile and have restrictions example control key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what I infer from your question is correct, this should work (assuming `Value="A"`):

```
variable_name = Value
attr = getattr(dic, variable_name)
data = attr.get(index)
```

or

```
data = attr[index]
```

Convert `index` to string before if you are passing index as an integer:

```
index = str(index)
```

Edit: As mentioned in the comment, you can use the [dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877290/what-is-the-dict-dict-attribute-of-a-python-class) attribute on modules/classes as well.

```
data = dic.__dict__[value][index]
```

Comment: Hi Jarvis thanks , but intend is I don't want to pass as A I want to make it dynamic like pass as argument of method todo like data=dic.Value[index] , it's a example I know it's wrong need help to correct it.

Comment: Alternatively, `data = dic.__dict__[value][index]`.

Comment: @user3724559 Please accept the answer to mark the issue resolved.

Comment: Yup have don't it apologize for delay